# JavaScript Regex for isolating words / splitting around words

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm trying to separate multiple words in a string, without removing anything, and form them into an array.
I'm using the .split method but can't find the exact pattern for multiple words and including spaces.

my string is:

```
const testSentence = 'a foxy dog met a dogged fox';
```

I want to split it at the words 'dog' and 'fox', so I get the array:

```
['a foxy ','dog',' met a dogged ','fox']
```

I've tried various combinations but nothing is working for all parts, so any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a non-capturing group in combination with word boundaries would do it:

```js
const s = 'a foxy dog met a dogged fox';

const r = s.split(/(?:\b(dog|fox)\b)/);

console.log(r);
```

If the empty segments bother you, you can easily filter them out:

```js
const s = 'a foxy dog met a dogged fox';

const r = s.split(/(?:\b(dog|fox)\b)/).filter(x => x);

console.log(r);
```